# Codeigniter Start and End Date Validation

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

I get the accurate result if i set the start date and end date when the year is 2017. But when the Start date in **15-October-2016** to **15-September-2017** it is not working and show the error message-

```
$error = "End date can't be older than begin date ";
```

Here is my code

```
        $data['beginDate'] = $this->input->post('beginDate');
        $data['endDate'] = $this->input->post('endDate');

        if($data['endDate'] < $data['beginDate']){
            $error = "End date can't be older than begin date ";
            $this->session->set_flashdata('error', $error);
            redirect('/search');
        }
        else{
            $this->load->model('personhistory');
            $data['rets'] = $this->personhistory->searchDetails();
            $data['sum'] = $this->personhistory->searchDetailsSum();
            $data['title'] = "Search Details";
            $this->load->view('search_results', $data);
        }
```

Is there any solution to get rid of this problem? Please Help...

Comment: Please be clear about what your test/example inputs are. What are the exact values of `$data['beginDate']` and `$data['endDate']` that cause the error?

Comment: Those values are date which are selected with JQuery Calendar

Comment: You have a time machine? I didn't think so. October always comes after September on my calendar.

Comment: Whenever someone is struggling with date time in php i remember my past Please take courage and use this http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/ best date time library you will ever get all possible validations can be done in laymen terms.

Comment: Sorry my mistake... the second date will not be **15-September-2016**, it will be **15-September-2017** . Now I have edited... @BrianGottier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP does not know what your strings are, and if the values are coming from posted data, then they are strings:

```
// These are strings
$s1 = '15-October-2016';
$s2 = '15-September-2016';
```

Instead, you need to create datetime objects for your comparison

```
$d1 = new DateTime('15-October-2016');
$d2 = new DateTime('15-September-2016');

if( $d1 < $d2 )
    echo 'First date comes before the second date';

if( $d1 > $d2 )
    echo 'First date comes after the second date';

if( $d1 == $d2 )
    echo 'First date and second date are the same';
```

Try this code and alter the dates, and you will see I am right.

UPDATE:

Technically you could also use strtotime

```
<?php

$s1 = strtotime('15-October-2016');
$s2 = strtotime('15-September-2016');

if( $s1 < $s2 )
    echo 'First date comes before the second date';

if( $s1 > $s2 )
    echo 'First date comes after the second date';

if( $s1 == $s2 )
    echo 'First date and second date are the same';
```

Comment: Sorry for my mistake...
the second date will not be **15-September-2016**, it will be **15-September-2017** 
I don't know what kind of problem it is, if the date is **14-October-2016** instead **15-October-2016** my code works fine. 

@BrianGottier

Comment: I don't know if you read any of my comments, or even tried my code, but I explained to you why your code isn't working. It's because you are trying to compare dates as strings. I provided you with two options, and both will work for you. First option is using PHP's DateTime class, and the other option is using PHP's strtotime function. Have you tried either of these? If you can't recognize that my answer is good, I don't have any reason to keep helping you. Try the code, and alter it as needed. You will see that it works for you.